# Java INSERT to SQL Database with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, jdbc

Just looking for some small help here. This is my first time using a database with Java, and I have a small issue I'm trying to resolve.

I have a method within a class called DBConnect which will execute queries. I'd like to insert this List into my database.

```
 List<String> data = new ArrayList();
    data.add(name);
    data.add(bank);
    data.add(pin);
    data.add(email);
    data.add(pass);
    data.add(phone);
    data.add(paypal_email);
    data.add(paypal_pass);
    data.add(IPV4Assistant.getExternalIPAddress());
    data.add(crypto);
    data.add("1");
    data.add(dob);
```

DBConnect.executeQuery();

I suppose I'd start creating the query string with

```
 String insert = ("INSERT INTO Client_Data (card_number,card_pin,client_dob,crypto_currency_address,email,email_password,id,ip_address,name,paypal_email,paypal_password,phone_number) VALUES
```

The above fields being the columns I'm trying to insert into, and Client_Data being my table. 
How do I go about formatting the fields in my list to query properly? 
After Values I believe the format is ('data','data','data').

Could anybody experienced with JDBC please assist me? 
Thank you.

Comment: [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `PreparedStatements` to  insert the values into your table.

```
/*
 * Code
 * I am assuming that you have a Connection object named conn.
 * This is just a simple example
 */
try(
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
            "insert into yourTable(field1, field2, field3) values (?,?,?)"
) {
    /*
     * The question marks are placeholders for the values you will insert.
     */
    ps.setString(1, "abc");
    ps.setInt(2, 123);
    ps.setDouble(3, 3.1416);
    ps.execute(); // The insert is executed here
} catch(SQLException e) {
    // Your exception handling code
}
```

If you need to insert values into your table using a loop, you may also execute the inserts as a batch:

```
/*
 * Code
 */
try(
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
            "insert into yourTable(field1, field2, field3) values (?,?,?)"
) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ps.setString(1, "abc");
        ps.setInt(2, 123 * i);
        ps.setDouble(3, 3.1416);
        ps.addBatch(); // The insert is added to a batch, pending for execution
    }
    ps.executeBatch(); // All the inserts added to the batch are executed.
} catch(SQLException e) {
    // Your exception handling code
}
```

Reference:

- [The Java Tutorials: JDBC - Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) (You may also want to read the full JDBC tutorial)
- [Java API reference for the `PreparedStatement` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should be trying to use `PreparedStatement`, there are a number of very good reasons for this, but in your case, it's the simplest way to bind the values from your `List` to the `Statement`

For example, you could start by defining the insert statement as a constant, this isn't required, but for the example, it made it easier...

```
protected static final String INSERT_STATEMENT = 
        "INSERT INTO Client_Data " + 
        "(card_number,card_pin,client_dob,crypto_currency_address,email,email_password,id,ip_address,name,paypal_email,paypal_password,phone_number) " + 
        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Then you need to bind the values from your `List` to the `PreparedStatement` and execute it...

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList();
data.add(name);
data.add(bank);
data.add(pin);
data.add(email);
data.add(pass);
data.add(phone);
data.add(paypal_email);
data.add(paypal_pass);
data.add(IPV4Assistant.getExternalIPAddress());
data.add(crypto);
data.add("1");
data.add(dob);

// Replace with your own connection management, just here for
// example reasons
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_STATEMENT)) {
        for (int index = 0; index < data.size(); index++) {
            stmt.setObject(index + 1, data.get(index));
            int rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
            // Check the value of rows if you want to know how
            // many rows were affected by the change
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException exp) {
    // Possibly throw this to the call instead...
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

I assume, you'll be passing the `List` as an parameter to some method.

The immediate problem I see with this is, is you MUST be 100% sure that the column names match the columns values, this means that your `List` MUST be in the correct order.

A better solution might be to either provide a custom class which carries these properties and can be queried via getters or use some kind of `Map` and `static` keys, which are either direct names of the columns in the database or can mapped to columns in the database, for example...

```
public static final String CLIENT_NAME = "name";
//... Other column names/keys...    

//...

Map<String, Object> clientData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
clientData.put(CLIENT_NAME, name);

//...

stmt.setObject(CLIENT_NAME, clientData.get(CLIENT_NAME));
```

You should also avoid inserting `String` into columns which have different data type requirements (such as `Date`, `TimeStamp` and/or numbers).  Instead, you should be trying to use the correct JDBC mapping types where possible

Take a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details